# SQL Formula Returns Inconsistent Precision

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The result of the two queries should be identical.  Same data.  Same formula.  Same cast.  One result is calculated in a query against a table variable, while the second is calculated against variables.  I have replaced the table variable with temp table and permanent table with identical results.

Why are my results different?

```
DECLARE
    @comm DECIMAL(20 , 6)
  , @quantity INT
  , @multiplier INT
  , @price DECIMAL(38 , 10)

SET @comm = 210519.749988;
SET @quantity = 360000;
SET @multiplier = 1;
SET @price = 167.0791666666;

DECLARE @t AS TABLE
    (
      [comm] [decimal](38 , 6)
    , [multiplier] [int]
    , [Quantity] [int]
    , [Price] [decimal](38 , 10)
    )

INSERT INTO @t
    VALUES
        ( @comm , @quantity , @multiplier , @price )

SELECT
        @comm = comm
      , @quantity = quantity
      , @multiplier = multiplier
      , @price = price
    FROM
        @t

SELECT
        CAST(comm / quantity / multiplier / price AS DECIMAL(32 , 10))
    FROM
        @t
UNION ALL
SELECT
        CAST(@comm / @quantity / @multiplier / @price AS DECIMAL(32 , 10));
```

Result

```
1. 0.0034990000
2. 0.0035000000
```

Same results against different servers.  SQL Server 2008 R2 Web Edition, Standard and Express and SQL Server 2012 Standard.

Comment: They are not all exactly equal. I see `@comm DECIMAL(20 , 6)` but `[comm] [decimal](38 , 6)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is due to the difference in precision of your two `DECIMAL` fields:

Changing @comm to `(38,6)`:

```
DECLARE
    @comm DECIMAL(38 , 6)
  , @quantity INT
  , @multiplier INT
  , @price DECIMAL(38 , 10)
```

I get:

```
---------------------------------------
0.0034990000
0.0034990000
```

Likewise changing `comm` in `@t` to `[comm] [decimal](20 , 6)` gets me:

```
---------------------------------------
0.0035000000
0.0035000000
```

If the fields are consistent, the results will be consistent.

Answer (score 4):

`@comm` is defined as decimal(20,6) while the `comm` column is decimal(38,6). You also assign a value with 7 decimal points to @comm, which only accepts up to 6 decimals

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx), decimals with a precision between 20-28 take 13 bytes while larger decimals use 17 bytes. When you `SELECT` the larger value stored in `comm` back into the smaller `@comm`variable some rounding is bound to happen.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if there is a difference in the implicit casts of your data types to the output data type between a select using fields and a select using in-memory variables.

When performing mathematical operations on variables/fields of differing data types, it is advisable to `CAST` them to the output (or the same intermediate) data type first.

In this case, your problem may be because of the `DECLARE @comm DECIMAL(20 , 6)`, which has a different precision to your output type of `DECIMAL(32, 10)`